# Are there loanwords from Portuguese used in Macau Cantonese?

Tags: grammar, cantonese, slang, loanwords

I'd like to know if there are some words from Macau Cantonese that are from Portuguese. As HK Cantonese has some words from English, I think Macau also can have some words. Thank you for any examples you can give.

I'm sorry for bothering you with this question, but I wasn't able to find these answers on any other website.

Answer (score 6):

Mostly food? The below examples are from Words.hk:

**马介休**

> loanword from "bacalhau" in Portuguese; Portuguese-style salted fish

> 馬介休撻
> maa5 gaai3 jau1 taat1
> bacalhau tart

**亞東**

> 「亞東」喺澳門叫法, 由葡文atum譯過來

**亞東魚**

> 一種魚嘅名；「吞拿」喺香港叫法, 由英文tuna譯過來; 「亞東」喺澳門叫法, 由葡文atum譯過來

---

Two places names:

**福尔摩沙**

> 近義 台灣
> 音譯自拉丁文及葡萄牙文嘅「Formosa」（「美麗」嘅意思）, 畀歐洲人用嚟稱呼台灣, 所以台灣又有「美麗島」之稱。
> Formosa; Taiwan

**欧罗巴**

> 名詞
> 外來語 | 專名 | 舊式
> 歐洲 嘅葡萄牙文、荷蘭文（Europa）傳入日本嗰時嘅音譯
> Europe
> jpn:ヨーロッパ（欧羅巴）

Comment: Interesting how the portuguese lateral approximant *lh* is rendered with /j/. Pretty close

Comment: Thank you, it was expected that words like "bacalhau" would be, but it's very cool to know how it's written and spoken, now i wonder how "pastel de nata" is known there.

Comment: @AlbertoRibeiro "pastel de nata," custard tarts? In Macau they are called 葡挞, which probably sounds terrible in Mandarin if you speak Portuguese, but in Cantonese it sounds much better. Usually they're just called 蛋挞 in other Chinese speaking locales though.